# Triggering ALM test sets (UFT tests) in Jenkins Unix slave

Tags: automated-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, hp-alm, uft

We have a Jenkins Unix slave through which builds are scheduled in different testing environments.

**Objective:**

To schedule a job in Jenkins unix slave to trigger 2 ALM test sets (containing 30 UFT test cases each) in 2 different physical machines.

**Could you please let me know the following:**

1. Is it possible to trigger a job to run ALM test sets(containing UFT scripts) in a Jenkins Unix slave ?
2. If yes, then is it possible in Jenkins to know that execution of all 60 scripts has been completed so that entire team can be notified of the results.

**Analysis done from our side:**

We checked with our Jenkins admin to provide a Windows slave but its not possible due to project restrictions. If we schedule a job in Jenkins to run a Windows batch file , it throws an exception as it tries to run the .bat file (to trigger a vbs file to invoke UFT script execution) in Jenkins Unix Slave workspace directory.

We are also planning to request the Jenkins admin to install ALM add in as we do not have access to Manage Jenkins page but not sure if ALM scripts will get triggered as it is a Unix slave.

Comment: I read like you can run uft scribts using vbs

Comment: Just see you can package the cscript.exe and all the required file and deploy it to the Jenkins .

Comment: Also try if you could create a windows docker image and run your scripts inside it